# Complicated bash variable syntax

Tags: bash

In one bash script i found the next construction:

```
if [[ "${xvar[id]:0:${#cnt}}" != "$cnt" ]]; then
```

Can someone explain what the above condition does?

Comment: Another way to help understand is that it behaves identically to `if [[ ${xvar[id]} = ${cnt}* ]]; then`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complicated expression is: `${xvar[id]:0:${#cnt}}`.

`$xvar` must be an array, possibly associative.  If it is associative, the part `${xvar[id]}` refers to the element of the array identified by the string 'id'; if not, then it refers to the element indexed by variable `$id` (you're allowed to omit the nested `$`), as noted by [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) in a comment.

The `${xxx:0:${#cnt}}` part of the expression refers to a substring from offset 0 to the length of the variable `$cnt` (so `${#cnt}` is the length of the string in the variable `$cnt`).

All in all, the test checks whether the first characters of `${xvar[id]}` are the same as the value of `$cnt`, so is the value in `$cnt` a prefix of the value in `${xvar[id]}`.

Comment: OMG. The substring part was the problematic one. Zilion thanx. ;)

Comment: `xvar` could be an indexed array as well; `id` could be a simple integer-valued parameter.